# Trouble converting Dec to Hex (Int to Char)

Tags: objective-c, c, char, hex

i know this seems to be a stupid question, but i'm really getting trouble here.

I'm working in a project where i have some functions i can´t modify. That is, i got some C functions (not really my speciality) inside my Obj. C code that i can modify.

So here it is... to explain a little what i have.

I'm receiving a NSData like "`\xce\x2d\x1e\x08\x08\xff\x7f`" . I have to put each \hex code in a char array, like this:

```
    cArray[1]=ce;
    cArray[2]=2d;
    cArray[3]=1e; 
    cArray[4]=08;
```

etc, etc... of course not LIKE THIS, but just so you understand. My initial move was to separe the NSData with subdataWithRange: and fill in an array with all "subdata". So the next move could be passing each position of that array to a char array, and that's where i got stuck.

I'm using something like (dont have my code right now)

```
for(int i=0 ; i<=64 ; i++) {
[[arrayOfSubData objectAtIndex:i] getBytes:&charArray[i]];
}
```

To fill the char array with the hex from my array of subData. That works almost perfectly. Almost.

Taking that example of cArray,  my `NSLog(@"pos%i: %x",i,charArray[i])` would show me:

```
pos1: ce
pos2: 2d
pos3: 1e
pos4: 8
```

And all the "left zeros" are supressed in that same way. My workaround for the moment (and i´m not sure if it  is the best practice here) is to take my subDataArray and `initWithFormat:` a string with it. With that i can transform the string to an int with `NSScanner scanHexInt:`, but then i´m stucked again when converting back my decimal int to a hexadecimal CHAR. What would be the best approach to fill my char array that way?

Any help or some "tough love" will be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the normal rules of [printf formatting](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/printf/) (which NSLog follows also) you want the following:

```
NSLog(@"pos%i: %02x", i, charArray[i]);
```

The '0' says to left pad with 0s and is a flag. The '2' says to ensure that output for that field is at least two characters. So that'll ensure that at least two characters are output and pad to the left with '0's in order to fill space.

Comment: Oh, I understand. Thanks!
But are you saying that - apart from the error on my NSLog formatting - all the bytes were being passed integrally to my charArray on that function with "getBytes"? It was really just an error on my NSLog and i don´t have to change nothing else?

Comment: It's a bit odd that you seem to be indexing your C array starting from position 1 rather than 0 and you seem to go a bit out of your way, but yes. The 0 is cut just because printf's (and NSLog's) default behaviour is to print the number in as few digits as possible. To save hopping through so many hoops, you should also check whether you can just use your original NSData as the array you want, e.g. NSLog(@"pos%i: %02x", i, [data bytes][i]);, so directly using the C array returned by the 'bytes' property of NSData.

Comment: Makes sense.. as i said, i´m not with my code right now, so probably the problem with the indexes were just a lack of attention while formulating my question here.. But i´ll check that tomorrow either. Thanks for your help!